# Creating a child tag in WordPress content

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the following code which pulls out blockquote information from Wordpress post content

HTML

```
<?php
        // get the content
        $block = get_the_content();

        // check and retrieve blockquote
        if(preg_match('~<blockquote>([\s\S]+?)</blockquote>~', $block, $matches))

        // output blockquote
        echo '<blockquote>'.$matches[1].'</blockquote>';
?>
```

This outputs the blockquote information in the following way

```
<blockquote>
    The text from the blockquote inside the post.
</blockquote>
```

I need the the output to be this ...

```
<blockquote>
   <p> The text from the blockquote inside the post. </p>
</blockquote>
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo '<blockquote>'.$matches[1].'</blockquote>';
```

with this

```
echo '<blockquote><p>'.$matches[1].'</p></blockquote>';
```